# How to find the matrix for this transformation relative to the standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I'm having a lot of trouble with this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call that a standard basis, because taking some vector (upper triangular matrix), its expression with respect to that basis, which triple of numbers arranged vertically, differs from the vector itself.

But in any case, writing down the matrix of $T$ relative to this basis$~U$ proceeds as always: for each vector in $U$ (taken in order), apply $T$ to it (this will require a $2\times 2$ matrix multiplication in the example at hand), express the result with respect to$~U$, and write down the coordinates found as the next column of your matrix$~B$.